# Notification body is empty onResume app flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using latest flutter and firebase_messaging. When i try to send a notification from cloud messaging console and app is in foreground. i am able to see the notification like below

```
onMessage: {notification: {title: Testing title, body: This i notification text}, data: {click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}}
```

When i switched the app to background and try to send same notification i am getting below message

```
onResume: {notification: {}, data: {collapse_key: com.example.chatapp, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1589541385520, google.delivered_priority: high, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 445401173125, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:1589541385747554%270c5cd8270c5cd8}}
```

Here notification is empty and i am unable to read this data
Can any one please guide me about this

Comment: for iOS or Android?

Comment: I am testing on android only at the moment.

Comment: In the console have you set the key/value in additional options?

Comment: yes this is added.  click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK

Comment: are you sending a data message?

Comment: No just a simple notification with title and body if you see my question's first part i have added it.

Comment: did you add the intent filter and the callbacks registered?

Comment: yes both were added.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: No sir. but i added info to the data propery

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to put it in simple words, when onResume event happens, you get an empty notification bloc because you don't need it there. If you want to navigate to a screen in your app after clicking the notification in order to display the notification message for example, then, you need to send your message in the data bloc (not only the notification bloc) so that you can access this bloc in onResume and navigate to your screen with the message to display.